# Chrome and MS Edge truncating filename in from Content-Disposition header

Tags: google-chrome, download, http-headers, microsoft-edge, window.open

I have a file saved with a long filename that I'm trying to download from where it's stored on the server. The filename is 254 characters long. When I download the file from Postman, it pulls back the whole filename in both the header and when it tries to save it (all 254 characters). The filename is stupid for testing:
`bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob123456_bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob123456_bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567.txt`

When I download it via Chrome, it shortens the filename to 177 characters.
`bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob123456_bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob.txt`

When I download it via Edge, it shortens the filename to 217 characters.
`bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob123456_bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob123456_bob1234567bob.txt`

In my Angular application, I'm download it using `window.open(<PATH>)`. I'm able to type in the rest of the characters, but I just don't get why it's shortening the filename when there are no bad special characters. To test out the download in Chrome and Edge, I'm hitting the  url directly which makes it hard to see the returned headers. But in Postman, I can see the full filename in the Content-Disposition header: `attachment;filename=bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob123456_bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob123456_bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567bob1234567.txt`

Is there something wrong with my header? Or does anyone have an idea about what to do to get the full filename I expect?

Comment: Is the filename length fixed on Chrome and Edge everytime?

Comment: It's adjusted every time to either 177 or 217 regardless of the actual filename length

Comment: If it is fixed to either 177 or 217, then it may be by design to restrict filename length (particularly in Chromium browsers). You may start a new issue thread on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list to confirm with them.